# state doesn't stay updated in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function App(){
   const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
        const initCategories = [
            { name: 'Restaurants', expenses: [], total: 0 },
            { name: 'Travel', expenses: [], total: 0 },
            { name: 'Dessert', expenses: [], total: 0 },
        ];
        setCategories(initCategories);
    }, []);
   
   ...
   
   const deleteCategory = (category) => {
        const updatedCategories = categories.filter(
            (d) => d.name !== category.name
        );
        setCategories(updatedCategories);
    };

}
```

I was trying to remove the category that was passed from child component and update the categories state accordingly. The issue I'm having is that my state doesn't stayed updated.

For example, when I delete one category upon some sort of interaction, I can see that one category is gone, but when I delete another one, the one that I deleted previously is now back.

**Expected:**

[category1, category2, category3] =(deleting category 3)> [category1, category2]

[category1, category2] =(deleting category 2)> [category1]

**What's happening:**

[category1, category2, category3] =(deleting category 3)> [category1, category2]

[category1, category2, category3] =(deleting category 2)> [category1, category3]

It seems to me that even though component is re-rendered and I can see the visual change because I updated my categories state, but on the next deleteCategory event, my state is somehow not updated, but back to its original state.

I'm confused since visually it updates...which tells me that my state is updated? Anyone has any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening becuase the useEffect re renders everytime and sets initCalories back to original.
Try this code :

```
function App(){
   const [categories, setCategories] = useState([
            { name: 'Restaurants', expenses: [], total: 0 },
            { name: 'Travel', expenses: [], total: 0 },
            { name: 'Dessert', expenses: [], total: 0 },
        ];)

 
   
   ...
   
   const deleteCategory = (category) => {
        let updatedCategories = categories.filter(
            (d) => d.name !== category.name
        );
        setCategories(updatedCategories);
    };

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. What you have is actually what I originally had...and it still had the same issue. The useEffect in my code should only run once, since it has empty array as its dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code for me, it's working as expected.

Here I am attaching my full-example,

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import "./style.css";


export default function App(){
   const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
     console.log("useEffetc")
        const initCategories = [
            { name: 'Restaurants', expenses: [], total: 0 },
            { name: 'Travel', expenses: [], total: 0 },
            { name: 'Dessert', expenses: [], total: 0 },
        ];
        setCategories(initCategories);
    }, []);
     const deleteCategory = (category) => {
        const updatedCategories = categories.filter(
            (d) => d.name !== category.name
        );
        setCategories(updatedCategories);
    };

   return (
    <div>
      <Childcomp categories={categories} deleteCategory={deleteCategory}/>
    </div>
  );
} 
function Childcomp(props){
  return (
    <>   
      {
        props.categories.map((cat)=>{
          return <div onClick={()=>{props.deleteCategory(cat)}}>{cat.name}</div>
        })
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting... mine still didn't work, but I found the solution that worked for me: `setCategories((arr) => arr.filter((d) => d.name !== category.name));` Not quite sure how this is different from what I had tho...?